# How to calculate probability of a specific type of independent chance intersection

Tags: math, probability, intersection

Let's say I have 4 events: A, B, C, and D. All of these events have an independent chance of 25% to occur.

It's possible that only 1 of these 4 events occur : A, B, C, or D.

It's possible that 2 of these 4 events occur at once : (A,B), (A,C), (A,D), (B,C), or (B,D).

It's possible that 3 of these 4 events occur at once : (A,B,C) or (B,C,D)

It's possible that all 4 events occur at once : (A,B,C,D)

I understand that the odds of (A,B) or (A,B,C) happening would be calculated by P(A)*P(B) or P(A)*P(B)*P(C) respectively. But how do you determine the odds of whether you get any one of the pairs of two or any one of the pairs of three?

Is it as simple as saying there are 12 possible outcomes and, for instance, any one pair of two would be 5 of those outcomes so 5/12 = 41.67%? Is this consistent regardless of what A, B, C, and D's individual occurrence chances are?

Comment: Can you express "any one of the pairs of two or any one of the pairs of three" in terms of P(something)?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a math question rather than a programming question. It might be a better fit on [mathematics.se].

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about probability and [math.se] instead of programming or software development.

Answer (score 0):

Your event "any two" is equivalent to:

- A and B but neither C nor D
- A and C but neither B nor D
- A and D but neither B nor C
- B and C but neither A nor D
- B and D but neither A nor C
- C and D but neither A nor B

Each of these events has probability (1/4)(1/4)(3/4)(3/4) = 9/256; there are six of them, so the total probability of any of them is 54/256.

For exactly three happening, we get four distinct events having probability 3/256 each. The overall probability of any of these is 12/256.

The probability of all and none are 1/256 and 81/256, respectively. Each can occur only one way.

Finally, there are four ways for only one of the four events to happen, and each of these outcomes has probability 27/256. The total is this 108/256.

81/256 + 108/256 + 54/256 + 12/256 + 1/256 = 256/256, as expected.